# Не подключаются шрифты в Nuxt

Tags: шрифты, nuxt.js

Хочу подключить шрифты, но они не подключаются, остальной css работает

Расположение файлов:

[image: расположение файлов в папке static]

css файл

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Resist Font", sans-serif;
  src: url("../fonts/ResistSansDisplayMediumOblique.otf") format('truetype');
  font-weight: 500;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Resist Font", sans-serif;
  src: url("../fonts/ResistSansTextLight.otf") format('truetype');
  font-weight: 300;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Golos UI", sans-serif;
  src: url("../fonts/GolosUIRegular.woff") format("woff"),
       url("../fonts/GolosUIRegular.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: А по прямой ссылке открываются?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar, да

Comment: смотрите в консоль там много чего бывает интересного, например путь по которому ищутся шрифты

Comment: используйте `opentype` вместо `truetype` (который для ttf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ходе исследования данного вопроса, выяснилось что браузеры отдают предпочтение форматам `woff2`, а `opentype` вовсе не пользуется спросом (*среда тестирования OS Kubuntu*).

**Chrome:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Firefox:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, лучше все же предоставлять им более широкий выбор (eot, woff2, woff, ttf) чтобы конкретный браузер сам мог выбрать наиболее подходящий для него формат:

`main.css` может выглядеть так:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Resist Sans Display';
    src: url('../fonts/ResistSansDisplay-MediumOblique.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/ResistSansDisplay-MediumOblique.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/ResistSansDisplay-MediumOblique.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/ResistSansDisplay-MediumOblique.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/ResistSansDisplay-MediumOblique.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: italic;
    font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Resist Sans Text';
    src: url('../fonts/ResistSansText-Light.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/ResistSansText-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/ResistSansText-Light.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/ResistSansText-Light.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/ResistSansText-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Golos UI';
    src: url('../fonts/GolosUI-Bold.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/GolosUI-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/GolosUI-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/GolosUI-Bold.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Golos UI';
    src: url('../fonts/GolosUI-Medium.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/GolosUI-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/GolosUI-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/GolosUI-Medium.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Golos UI';
    src: url('../fonts/GolosUI-Regular.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/GolosUI-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/GolosUI-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('../fonts/GolosUI-Regular.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

я сделал тестовые классы для проверки работоспособности приведенного импорта:

```
 .testResistSansDisplay {
    font-family: Resist Sans Display;
    color: rgb(2, 68, 68);
}

.testResistSansDisplayText {
    font-family: Resist Sans Text;
    color: rgb(2, 68, 68);
}

.testGolosUIBold {
    font-family: 'Golos UI'; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-style: normal;
}

.testGolosUIMedium {
    font-family: 'Golos UI';
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}

.testGolosUIRegular {
    font-family: 'Golos UI'; 
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Полезные ссылки:**

Для конвертации я воспользовался сайтом https://transfonter.org/ он позволяет загрузить сразу несколько шрифтов и конвертировать их в выбранные форматы за один раз, скачать архив с демо-страницей, а так же посмотреть результат до скачивания.

Так же может быть полезна данная статья [Подключение шрифтов из папки. CSS свойство font-face](https://sitist.ru/info-add-fonts.htm)